remove empty space from -translate-y using tailwind css
I have an issue where there's empty space in my profile container which I'd like removed from the
profile container
    <div className='h-auto w-[650px] z-10 rounded-xl' style={{ backdropFilter: `blur(400px)`, backgroundColor: bgColorWithOpacity }}>
    {user.Banner && (
        <div className='h-full w-full'>
            <img src={user.Banner} className='rounded-t-xl' alt={user.Username} />
        </div>
    )}
    <div className={`items-center grow flex flex-col z-20 ${user.Banner ? '-translate-y-24' : ''} px-8 py-8`}>
        <img src={user.Avatar} className='w-[128px] h-[128px] object-cover rounded-md' alt='' />
        <h1 className='mt-4 font-bold text-2xl'>{user.username}</h1>
        {user.Bio && (
            <p className='text-sm mt-2'>{user.Bio}</p>
        )}
    </div>
</div>


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This is an updated version of your code
<div className='relative h-auto w-[650px] z-10 rounded-xl' style={{ backdropFilter: `blur(400px)`, backgroundColor: bgColorWithOpacity }}>
    {user.Banner && (
        <div className='relative'>
            <img src={user.Banner} className='rounded-t-xl w-full' alt={user.Username} />
            <div className='absolute inset-0 flex flex-col items-center justify-center mt-24'>
                <img src={user.Avatar} className='w-[128px] h-[128px] object-cover rounded-md' alt='' />
                <h1 className='mt-4 font-bold text-2xl'>{user.username}</h1>
                {user.Bio && (
                    <p className='text-sm mt-2'>{user.Bio}</p>
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
    )}
    {!user.Banner && (
        <div className='flex flex-col items-center px-8 py-8'>
            <img src={user.Avatar} className='w-[128px] h-[128px] object-cover rounded-md' alt='' />
            <h1 className='mt-4 font-bold text-2xl'>{user.username}</h1>
            {user.Bio && (
                <p className='text-sm mt-2'>{user.Bio}</p>
            )}
        </div>
    )}
</div>


it seems like the background is missing for items below such as the username and bio, thanks for help though!

Sure , you are welcome
